# Maven support for Jdeveloper 11.1.7.0

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, jdeveloper

Does Jdeveloper 11.1.7.0 supports Maven integration? Is there any plugins available for it? Please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Real maven support comes with 12.1.3 here you can use the official Oracle maven repository. 
11.1.1.7 isn't an option.